# Cloudformation RDS template cannot resolve security group id

Tags: mysql, templates, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

I have a CF that deploys a MySql database and some resources to AWS. I want the script to be general and should be able to use it for different environments. For one of those resources (master db), I have a different security group configuration which is environment-specific. I create security groups for each environment conditional and are called VaultSecurityGroupInEnv1, VaultSecurityGroupInEnv2, etc. There is map that saves names of security groups for each environment. here are my configurations:

```
Mappings:
  RegionMap:
    environment1:
      VaultSG: VaultSecurityGroupInEnv1
    environment2:
      VaultSG: VaultSecurityGroupInEnv2

Resources:
  VaultSecurityGroupInEnv1:
    Condition: IsEnv1Environment

  VaultSecurityGroupInEnv2:
    Condition: IsEnv2Environment

  MasterDB:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      VPCSecurityGroups:
        - !ImportValue DbSgId
        - !Sub
          - '${vGroup}'
          - vGroup: !FindInMap
            - RegionMap
            - !Ref Environment
            - VaultSG
```

for which I get the following error:

```
Invalid security group , groupId= vaultsecuritygroupinF.groupid, groupName=. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue;
```

The output from !Sub is retrieved and resolved as a name string, not as a resource. Using !Ref vaultsecuritygroupinF.GroupId works fine. any idea how to use map and sub correctly?

Thanks

Comment: What `VaultSG` is? Is it name or group-id of the SG?

Comment: It is the name of the SG

Comment: Can you provide more complete example what you are doing. Its confusing what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I think it would be better if you edited your question with correctly formated and complete code example.

Comment: yes, will edit the question

Comment: @Marcin let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `FindInMap` the way you are trying. It will just resolve to the **literal strings** `VaultSecurityGroupInEnv1` or `VaultSecurityGroupInEnv2`. It will not resolve to the actual resources of the same name.

Instead, I think the following should be possible:

```
MasterDB:
  Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
  Properties:
    VPCSecurityGroups:
      - !ImportValue DbSgId
      - !If
        - IsEnv1Environment
        - !Ref VaultSecurityGroupInEnv1
        - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
      - !If
        - IsEnv2Environment
        - !Ref VaultSecurityGroupInEnv2
        - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

Comment: thanks this solved my issue, I have already tried this but I was missing !Ref for "AWS::NoValue".